# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tflearn' - что делать?

Tags: python, tensorflow

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tflearn'

Хотя я скачал tflearn с помощью `pip install`, а затем скачал tensorflow с помощью `python -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0-py3-none-any.whl`.

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема.

Answer (score 0):

Версия Python?

```
pip3 install tflearn
```

Возможно,версия питона просто не поддерживает этот модуль.Введи это в cmd и если ошибка - меняй версию,которая указана в cmd

Comment: Последняя версия.